# How do I add missing keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I upgraded to Kubuntu 18.04 recently but do not see the Slovak keyboard layout (in "Keyboard -  System Settings Module" ). Is there any way how to add it?

This layout was normally available for older Kubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a Kubuntu desktop at the moment, but you can try to add it system wide.

Open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing. If you for instance have the English (US) layout set by default, you probably find these two lines:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
```

You can add Slovak by changing those lines so they look like this:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,sk"
XKBVARIANT=","
```

Hopefully Slovak will then be available after next reboot.

*Edit:*

`/etc/default/keyboard` corresponding to `setxkbmap()` command in comment:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,sk"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT=",qwerty"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Comment: Thank you Gunnar, modifying that config file helped to me. It did not affect "Keyboard" app list of installed layouts, but that app display correct flag/code for that Slovak keyboard (when I switch from the 'us" to "sk" and back). I investigated further and found this command:

Comment: ... 

`setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout "us,sk" -variant ",qwerty" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"`

at https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html

But that does not work after reboot.

Using `strace` for that app I found `${HOME}/.config/kxkbrc` which is the config file that app use, so I put `LayoutList=us,sk(qwerty)`.

Comment: @MartinFlaska: It you want the settings in that `setxkbmap()` command survive a reboot, then edit the config file accordingly (see edited answer).

Comment: I understand, it works, but that do not affect kb layout list which "Keyboard" app (`kcmshell5 --args=--tab=layouts kcm_keyboard`) shows in settings layout tab. So I was curious why. Anyway, thank you for you help, it pointed my right direction. Still I have no idea why it do not offer Slovak layout out of the box.

Comment: @MartinFlaska: Me neither. It's probably some Kubuntu specific issue.