# Adding a second keyboard layout in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 and I am facing a problem with the keyboard layout. I have English as my first language and would like to add Greek as a second one also.

I have initially followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065209/how-do-i-add-missing-keyboard-layout) which suggested editing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file.

At the present the content of my config file are:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,gr"
XKBVARIANT=",qwerty"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

which does not made any major difference in my DE.
I have also tried from *KDE System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Layouts tab*
[image]

At present I have 3 languages in my keyboard layout switcher:
English (US)
Greek (qwerty)
Greek (Greek).

Although I see the 3 options (only with right click though which I am not sure it's the default behavior) I cannot choose a different than the default (English) either by mouse or by keyboard.

I added 2 keyboard shortcuts to change layouts but to no avail.
[image]

Edit:
(Some extra information that might come handy)

In the Regional Settings I have added Greek also 
[image]

I am not sure what I have done wrong but adding one extra language layout shouldn't be so hard. So, how can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I managed to overcome the problem by a somewhat bizarre solution. At least in my case the system seemed to be able to toggle between English and Greek after this approach.

- I added a 3rd language in the *Configure layout...* (in my case Spanish)
- Enable *Spare layouts*
- Also (I am not sure this is necessary but I followed that step also) I installed the 3rd language to *Regional Settings* dialog.
- After logout I was able to use the keyboard shortcut.

The funny thing is that I removed the 3rd language after that and it still works (I only kept English and Greek which was my initial intention).

Hope that this would be helpful to anyone facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In system settings/input devices/keyboard/layout I first clicked on the middle square and then added the Greek Lang. Then up right I set the "Change layout shortcut" to the one I preferred